# How to convert NSString to char[] array in object C

Tags: objective-c, c, nsstring, char

I have a very long string but want to convert it to a char array, something like `unsigned char[4]`, for example:

```
NSString *str = "Thisisaverylongstringofstringsjoinedtogether";
unsigned char c[4] = str;
```

I hope someone understands what I want and help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [str cString] to get a char array of the same lenght of the String.

If you just want the first 4 chars create a substring before with [str substringWithRange:4] or after where you just memcpy a part of the complete char Array.

Comment: Thanks Maffo. But is there a way i can compress the string so i can get the whole string into my tiny char[4] array?

Comment: `cString` is deprecated; use `UTF8String` instead.

Comment: what do you mean by "compress"? Do you don't to shrink it? If you want to store the whole String into a char array, the array has to have the same lenght than the string. If you just need a portion of the String, say the first 4 chars then you could use the substringWithRange Method to create a smaller String and then convert this string to char array.

Comment: I like to shrink the String if there's a way of doing that, because i need the whole string. Am sending it to a server that expects char[4].

Comment: When you have to pass a char[4] you can only send 4 Characters, not the whole String.

Comment: either `cString` or `UTF8String`, both returning `char *`. My requirement is `NSString -> char[]`. Please help....